How can I get minor ticks with a logarithmic x-axis of base 2?
Creating a plot with a logarithmic x axis of base 2 doesn't have a minor tick grid. Adding minor ticks manually yields the error "Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, minor ticks are not supported for this log basis."
I don't see any reason for that. A base of 2 makes sense for my data and minor ticks between the major ticks would be helpful, especially between x=1 and x=2, where a lot is happening in my plot. Is there some trick around this seemingly arbitrary restriction?
Minimal example of my plot (I took the lines out, since they are extracted from a csv file):
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        grid=both,
        minor grid style={gray!40},
        major grid style={gray!40},
        width=\textwidth,
        height=0.6\textwidth,
        log basis x=2,
        xmin=0.8,
        xmax=1024,
        xtick={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256},
        xticklabels={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256}
    ]
        \addplot[const plot, dotted, thick, domain=0.1:2048] {0.82};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



How many minor ticks do you want e.g. between 2 and 4, 32 and 64 etc.?

I'd experiment with it once I knew how to do it. But I was thinking maybe 3, i.e one at .5 and one at .25 and .75 respectively. Maybe only within the first interval from 1 to 2. Not sure yet.

Still doesn‘t make much sense to me, neither mathematically, nor for visual communication of a more fundamental feature of data. May be, if you add data, your situation becomes easier to understand. Thank you

One can generate a list of "extra ticks" which can be given a separate style.  I've never had much luck with "minor ticks".

I ended up solving this as John Kormylo suggested by using "extra ticks".
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        grid=major, % minor doesn't work because of base 2 :(
        major grid style={gray!75},
        width=\textwidth,
        height=0.6\textwidth,
        log basis x=2,
        xmin=0.8,
        xmax=1024,
        xtick={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256},
        xticklabels={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256},
        extra x ticks={1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 14, 20, 24, 28, 40, 48, 56, 80, 96, 112, 160, 192, 224},
        extra x tick style={grid=major, tick style={draw=none}, major grid style={gray!25}},
        extra x tick labels={}
    ]
        \addplot[const plot, dotted, thick, domain=0.1:2048] {0.82};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


If there is any better solution let me know!
